# Voltage comparator

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, voltage-regulator, comparator

I have a circuit where I have to read high and low logic level through a micro-controller.

Condition:

- When the input voltage is above 15V, it should be HIGH logic (2V to 5V.)
- When the input voltage is below 12V, it should be LOW logic (0 volt.)

I don't have ADC PIN, so I have to use some external circuit for this.
Someone suggested a voltage comparator, but I don't know how.

Comment: How accurate does this need to be?  What power supply rail voltages do you have available?  Please update your question with this information.

Comment: You use a resistor divider to produce a voltage reference that you feed to either the + or - input of the comparator. Your other signal goes to the remaining input. When a comparator's + input is higher than the - input, it outputs a HI. Can you work out yourself what you need to do from there?

Comment: @DwayneReid there are 3.3v and 5v both power supply available. accuracy 0.5v allowable.

Comment: @DKNguyen thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have a ADC pin, I assume you have GPIO which cna be configures a input pin. First you have to condition the input signal. You can use a voltage divider to bring down the actual input voltage by 5times. So, the signal from 15 V and 12 V will be brought down to 3 and 2.4 V respectively.

to downconvert the higher 15V to a lower value, you can use voltage divider:
[image]

---

You can put a Schmidt trigger ( the below one is in the [inverting](https://www.electronicshub.org/schmitt-trigger-basics/)  configuration) circuit to use. Assuming you have a 3.3 V rail and MCU is also running at 3.3 V, you can make it work.
[Example from here:](https://www.random-science-tools.com/electronics/inverting-schmitt-trigger-calculator.htm) 
[image]

---

1. The input might go above 15 V too. in that case, you should clamp the input signal a the GPIO using diodes OR you can use a TVS or a Zener diode.
2. The resistors might be not practical if the signal is fast changing. in that case, you may have to add a buffer circuit.

Comment: Can I use voltage comparator instead of Schmidt trigger ?
btw thank you for valuable response.

Comment: Do you mean the internal comparator present in the MCU? Or the external comparator? Can you provide datasheet of the MCU you are using?

Comment: @AaravSoni A Schmitt trigger is just a comparator circuit wired to have hysteresis. That triangle with the + and - is a comparator. R3 going from the output to the + input gives it positive feedback which makes it a comparator with hysteresis, which makes it a Schmitt trigger.